# How to implement kiosk mode in angular application?

Tags: angular

I want to open my angular application in kiosk mode.

How to enable it in angular code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Angular cannot control application's mode.  The browser has to be opened in kiosk mode.

Comment: So you want it in a stand-alone browser window without the navigation bar? If so that would require that you add the pieces needed to make it a PWA and that your users install your PWA.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs for the specific browser or operating system that you want to run the app in. Kiosk mode is specific to the run-time environment, it is not specific to the UI framework.